# Cython cannot convert float ndarray to int ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I am having a very weird error when I cast a numpy ndarray from one type to the other in Cython. For instance when I write the following convert_test.pyx:

```
cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

DTYPE = np.float32
ctypedef np.float32_t DTYPE_t

def convert_to_int(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] float_matrix):
    cdef np.ndarray[np.int, ndim=2] int_matrix=float_matrix.astype(np.int)
    return int_matrix
```

compile it and test:

```
from convert_test import convert_to_int
a_int=convert_to_int(np.zeros((2,2)).astype(np.float32))
```

I got the very familiar message:

**ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'int object' but got 'long'**

It is probably super obvious but I don't quite see it yet.

Comment: Python 3 doesn't have an `int` type. It has been implemented as `long`. So, maybe you should convert to `long` instead of `int`. Although, I have no experience with Cython, so I can't say if it would work.

Comment: I am using python2 but maybe you are on to something.

Comment: @jean See my answer this works making memoryviews of different types in Cython. If you really want ndarray format I can write that out for you but it should be pretty intuitive if you compare my 2nd sample to the 1st sample.  Also note that just casting from a single to an int it truncates the decimal points (no rounding) so this function may not be what you intend to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just do this?  Compiles and works just fine on my computer:

```
cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

DTYPE = np.float32
ctypedef np.float32_t DTYPE_t

def convert_to_int(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] float_matrix):
    int_matrix = np.array(float_matrix, dtype=np.int32)
    return int_matrix
```

Or if you really want a memoryview:

```
def convert_to_int(DTYPE_t[:,:] float_matrix):
    cdef int[:,:] int_matrix = np.array(float_matrix, dtype=np.int32)
    return np.asarray(int_matrix)
```

The second answer I just converted the older `ndarray` parameters to the modern `typed memoryviews` syntax for `int_matrix` and `float_matrix`.  The style above is your contiguous memory format `[:,:]` for a matrix (like NumPy defaults to with numpy.zeros for example).

Note that the function you posted is just going to truncate everything after the decimal point (no rounding up/down) so be sure that's what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use _t types in your declaration: cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=2].